# Fill only values between observations observed

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

Let suppose the following dataset :

| ID | Number |
| --- | --- |
| AX | 1 |
| AX | NA |
| AX | NA |
| AX | 2 |
| AX | NA |
| AX | NA |
| AX | NA |

I would like to only fill NA which are between real observations observed, such as :

| ID | Number |
| --- | --- |
| AX | 1 |
| AX | 1 |
| AX | 1 |
| AX | 2 |
| AX | NA |
| AX | NA |
| AX | NA |

I tried to do it with tidyr::fill  (DF %>% fill(Number)) but i cannot reproduce those results because it fills all the NA values. How can i do it ?

Comment: Try `tidyr::fill(DF, Number, .direction = "up")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one method that `fill`s and restores the `NA` for those cases where follow-on non-`NA` values were not found.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # fill
quux %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(hasmore = rev(cumany(!is.na(rev(Number))))) %>%
  fill(Number) %>%
  mutate(Number = if_else(hasmore, Number, Number[NA])) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 7 × 3
#   ID    Number hasmore
#   <chr> <chr>  <lgl>  
# 1 AX    1      TRUE   
# 2 AX    1      TRUE   
# 3 AX    1      TRUE   
# 4 AX    2      TRUE   
# 5 AX    <NA>   FALSE  
# 6 AX    <NA>   FALSE  
# 7 AX    <NA>   FALSE
```

I use `Number[NA]` instead of just `NA` because I'm not certain if *your* `Number` is character, numeric, or integer; `Number[NA]` is *never* wrong, it will always do as intended, but using the wrong type of `NA` (there are at least ten kinds of `NA`) can produce an error.